# psycopg2 cannot connect even though pgadmin can

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect to a Postgres database on AWS with psycorg. it's all pretty standard:

```py
param = {
        'database': "******",
        'user': "***",
        'password': "***",
        'host': '*******.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'port': 5432
    }
    psycopg2.connect(
        **param
        )
```

I can connect on pgadmin, and on pycharm, but psycorg2 throws me the error

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name '****' nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Comment: Did you translate that error message from some other language?  That wording really seems off.

Comment: Is psycopg2 running on the same host as the pgAdmin server is?

Comment: which asterisks in the error message line up with which ones in the config?  Is it really necessary to obscure the hostname?  If your security depends on your hostname remaining a secret, you don't really have much security.

Comment: the database is publicly facing, just want to avoid any potential problem. It's not a production app just a hobby, so I don't really care abt the security as much.
except the python spread * in front of param, everything else is obscured. the database is on AWS RDS, and both pgadmin and psycopg2 are running on my own computer. That error message is word for word from psycopg2.

Comment: the * in the error message line up with the host name.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your DNS resolver.  I don't know why it would work for one program and not another, though.  Is this a Mac?  I've only seen references to the 'nodename nor servname' verbiage for macs.  Maybe you could connect to the IP address rather than the hostname, or hardcode the mapping into /etc/hosts or whatever it is Macs do.

Comment: This is a m2 Mac. I did suspect its a DNS issue, since I couldn't reach the endpoint with psql or ns. However, if that's the problem then jdbc and pgadmin should not be able to reach the database either. I'm just wondering what they are doing differently to reach the database.

Comment: Maybe they are linked against a different DNS resolver.so file (or whatever Macs call those files).  It is probably best investigated as a system problem, not a PostgreSQL problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but a work around, I'm able to connect by using the jdbc api instead.